# Dojo build(ed) doesnt work on Android 2.2 browser

Tags: cordova, dojo

I was testing modules for a webapp using dojo 1.8. And it uses many modules. Everything works like a charm but slowly when I use the version not builded. When I do the same thing with the version I builded using http://build.dojotoolkit.org/ I get an error:

```
01-27 17:12:49.744: E/browser(10771): Console: Error: scriptError 
http://blog.arthurmolina.com/dojotest/lib/dojo.js:15
```

This problem occurs only on Android 2.2 Browser version. Well, I just tested on it and the version 4.0 and on my iPhone. On desktop browser there is no problem.

Also I see that if I take out those lines:

```
"dojox/mobile/ValuePickerDatePicker",
"dojox/mobile/ValuePickerTimePicker",
```

it doesnt show that error again...

I could use this without the build version but I want to wrap in Phonegap and it doesnt work if I dont do this.

You can find the app test working in http://blog.arthurmolina.com/dojotest/

So, what to do?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but I suspect you might be running into the problem of Android not accepting resources starting with underscore. The two modules you are mentionning have dependencies into _TimePickerMixin which might create the problem. The problem would be solved by doing a build of your application that includes _TimePickerMixin to remove the need for the underscore files. See: https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojox/mobile/faq.html#id3 (the build you did might have ignored that file for one reason?)